# How to create a function like in Python

Tags: functions, programming, python

I want to call a function that would perform a function rather than assigning an expression to them.

I.e.

```
functionA[string_]

n=1; wordSplit = {};
stringWord = string; 
While[n-1 != StringLength[stringWord], wordSplit = Append[wordSplit, StringTake[stringWord, {n,n}]] n++];
```

How can I call this 'functionA' with a string input rather than directly modifying the variable in its cell?

Comment: take a look at := and Block, use function[input_String]:=Block[{},code] and than call it via function["test string"]

Comment: Awesome Block is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alhough your function may be an example and you could use `Block` or `Module` to build your list using looping and `Append`, list manipulation offers great advantages.

For the example of splitting a string (including `WhiteSpaceCharacter`) the following are  ways to do it (starting with the built-in function `Characters`).

```
Characters["this is"]

(*mapping StringTake to list of positions, i.e. take 1st, 2nd,... etc*)

fun[str_] := StringTake[str, {#}] & /@ Range[StringLength@str]

(* using Table*)

tab[str_] := Table[StringTake[str, {j}], {j, StringLength@str}]

(*extracting characters*)

StringCases["this is", 
 x : (LetterCharacter | WhitespaceCharacter) -> x]
```

I post this just as motivation to explore the documentation and this site which as excellent resources, e.g. searchng for alternatives to  loops in Mathematica.

Comment: Thank you, that is super neat. I completely agree with you. I read somewhere that looping is not always a solution and most of the time more slower than using already built-in functions. I will explore the documentation more.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe using `Module`, something like this:

```
functionA[string_] := Module[{stringWord, n, wordSplit},
  n = 1;
  wordSplit = {};
  stringWord = string;
  While[n - 1 != StringLength[stringWord], 
  wordSplit = 
    Append[wordSplit, StringTake[stringWord, {n, n}]] n++];
  wordSplit
]
```

Another option might be to use `Block`.

Comment: Great! Module and Block both worked.

Comment: @TadashiKikuno You should use `Module` for localization unless you *know* you need `Block`. ([see here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)).  These are used for localization.  If there are no variables to localize, just use `CompoundExpression`, i.e. `f[] := (command1; command2; ...)`